# Delphi/C++Builder TBitmap: How to determinine scanline order?

Tags: gdi+, gdi, c++builder, vcl

Delphi's TBitmap type is basically a wrapper over a GDI BITMAP and PALETTE, and can support both top-down and bottom-up scanline ordering.

I have a TBitmap which I need to convert to GDI+ Bitmap, in order to rotate and composite it.

My bitmap is 32-bit ARGB, which windows supports, but VCL doesn't natively 'understand'.

```
TBitmap *bmp;
...
```

When I use the following constructor, the alpha channel doesn't work for compositing, but otherwise everything works.

```
Gdiplus::Bitmap b(bmp->Handle, NULL);
```

So, I tried the constructor below, which takes size, pixel data and format params.

```
Gdiplus::Bitmap b(bmp->Width,  bmp->Height, bmp->Width *4, PixelFormat32bppARGB,   
    (BYTE*) bmp->ScanLine[bmp->Height-1]); // bottom up storage
```

This gets the alpha, but the bitmap is upside down, so I tried this

```
Gdiplus::Bitmap b(bmp->Width,  bmp->Height, - bmp->Width *4, PixelFormat32bppARGB,   
    (BYTE*) bmp->ScanLine[0]);  // negative stride for bottom up bitmaps?!
```

Now, that works, but of course I'm hard-coded into bottom-up bitmaps. However, I can't find a way of determining if the TBitmap is top-down or bottom-up. They're stored internally with negative height but the height value is massaged before it's passed back to user code.

How can I find out the scanline ordering, or - better yet - is there another way of creating a GDIPlus bitmap from a TBitmap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TBitmap::ScanLine` property accounts for top-down and bottom-up.  For a bottom-up bitmap, `ScanLine[0]` returns the last row, and `ScanLine[Height-1]` returns the first row, of the raw pixel data.  For a top-down bitmap, `ScanLine[0]` returns the first row, and `ScanLine[Height-1]` returns the last row, of the raw pixel data.

To determine if a `TBitmap` is bottom-up or top-down, you have to manually retreive its [`BITMAPINFOHEADER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183376.aspx) structure, which `TBitmap` does not natively expose.  You can use the Win32 API [`GetObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144904.aspx) function to retreive a [`DIBSECTION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183567.aspx) structure, which has a [`BITMAPINFOHEADER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183376.aspx) member.